# My BCC recipients are not receiving emails

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, sendgrid

This is my method for building the e-mail object and sending it:

```
public async Task SendEmail(List<ApplicationUser> bccUsers, string subject, string contentText, string contentHtml)
{
    if (bccUsers.Count > 0)
    { 
        var client = new SendGridClient("MyClientKey");
        var from = new EmailAddress("noreply@domain", "MyProjectName");
        var to = new EmailAddress("noreply@domain", "MyProjectName");
        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, contentText, contentHtml);
        foreach (ApplicationUser user in bccUsers)
        {
            msg.AddBcc(user.Email, $"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}");
        }
        await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
    }
}
```

I have confirmed that all the e-mail addresses are receiving other e-mails.

When inspecting the `msg`-object, all the BCC recipients are there:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**
I don't know if this is relevant info, but all the three e-mail addresses are being forwarded to my gmail-address. I am only checking emails there.

One of those addresses is in use, and I am receiving emails to it regularly.

The other two addresses I have just created for testing purposes. They do not have mailboxes of their own at the hosting company, only forwarding to my gmail address.

Comment: Just to have that out of the way: The addresses are correct and work if you send an email outside of the software?

Comment: @Fildor That is correct.